# Importing Wordpress database into Laravel Valet, rows not being imported

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, laravel-valet, valet

I'm copying a Wordpress site from a server to a local Valet environment.

When I export the database, I can see in the **wp_options** table that the rows such as the *site_url* etc are present.

Yet when I import the database into Valet via either `wp-cli` or `phpMyAdmin`, the **wp_options** table is missing all the usual rows you'd expect to find in a Wordpress site.

Instead there's just a handful of data for `transients` etc.

A similar thing happens with other tables as well.

I'm running:

- macOS 10.4.3
- phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1
- wp-cli 2.2.0
- Laravel Valet 2.3.3

I've been exporting/importing *just* the **wp_options** table to speed up the time needed to troubleshoot things.

I've tried altering export/import settings such as *compression* and *maximising output compatibility* but to no avail.

My database knowledge is rather limited after that.

If I repeat the same process using a database from a different project, it works fine.

I'll paste sample **wp_options** data below.

Troublesome **wp_options** (slightly edited to hide client details):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example_options`;
CREATE TABLE `example_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `option_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO `example_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(1, 'siteurl', 'https://www.example.com', 'yes'),
(2, 'blogname', 'Example Site', 'yes'),
(3, 'blogdescription', '', 'yes'),
...
```

Compared to this dump from a different project which works fine.
Note the Wordpress version here is different which changes the order of the rows that are added.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_options`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2376 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

```
LOCK TABLES `wp_options` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_options` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES
(1,'siteurl','https://www.example.com','yes'),(2,'home','https://www.example.com','yes'),
(3,'blogname','Example Site','yes'),
...
```

Once I've imported the database, browsing to the site results in a `Error establishing database connection` error.

If I try to use `wp-cli` I sometimes get `Error: One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.` otherwise it's `Error establishing database connection`.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has noticed it works if you untick the `Enclose export in a transaction` option when initially exporting the database.

This will tide me over for now as it's only local projects it affects.